# fuelphp can't access the page ( .htaccess is not working... )

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, fuelphp

First of all, i'm new to FuelPHP, so it will be something very easy but i can't find the answer on the internet so i'm hoping that you guys can help me.

The thing is that i'm following [THIS](http://ucf.github.io/fuelphp-crash-course/) tutorial about FuelPHP.

I've setup wamp with an virtial directory in `D:\www_ander\webshop`. That is the root with the `.htaccess` and the `index.php` and the folder `assets`

I've got the `fuel` folder in the folder `www_ander`.

I've did what the tutorial said ( Edit the config / autoload, create the files and database ) with the following command ( i ran this in command promt from the folder `D:\www_ander` )

```
php oil generate scaffold messages name:string message:text
php oil refine migrate
```

I don't get any errors, and the database is created succesfully. But when i go to my website (this is localhost, i've edidted the host file of windows ):

```
http://webshop.nl/messages/
```

I get an `404, Not Found` page. I even tryed it with `/index/` appended to the URL, but that didn't work also.

So my question is, what did i wrong? Why isn't this working as it should?!? Is my URL wrong or is it another issue?

Mayby inrellevant, but here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Multiple Environment config, set this to development, staging or production
# SetEnv FUEL_ENV production

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
    #AllowOverride All
    #RewriteBase /wherever/fuel/is

    # Restrict your site to only one domain
    # !important USE ONLY ONE OPTION

    # Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Remove index.php from URL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With}    !^XMLHttpRequest$
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}              ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$            $1 [R=301,NS,L]

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # deal with php5-cgi first
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>

        # for normal Apache installations
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

        # for Apache FGCI installations
        <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

**------ UPDATE ------**

I'm still looking for the answer, but i've already found an workaround. When i visit `http://webshop.nl/index.php/messages/` it does work. So it seems like the .htaccess isn't fully working. But as far as i see, it should work. So do you guys know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the problem was. Id had to do with my virtual host setup.

The thing is that i didn't specify to allow overides. So after i inserted this part in my virtual host file, it worked:

```
<Directory "D:\www_ander">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

So the whole virtual host file now looks like this:

```
<Directory D:\www_ander\>
    Order Deny,Allow   
    Allow from all 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
    DocumentRoot "D:\www_ander" 
    ServerName webshop.nl
    ServerAlias www.webshop.nl
    <Directory "D:\www_ander">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```